XPath syntax for pagination
Need help in arriving at an XPath for the image pasted here:
enter image description here
I tried this:
private readonly Label _pagenumber = new Label(By.XPath("//div[@class='btn-pagination btn-flat active']/button[./span[text()='Next']]"), "Next");

Your first predicate [@class='btn-pagination btn-flat active'] should be on the button, not on the div.
Change your XPath to this:
"//div/button[@class='btn-pagination btn-flat active'][span[text()='Next']]"

